# Open debug snapshot link is not visible?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have installed package for snapshot debugger and also made changes to applicationinsight.config. but when i see exception there is showing Collect debug snapshots.

Comment: we need a little more information about what exactly you're doing and what exactly you're expecting to help you.

Comment: when i click on exception within failure tab in application insights. i am getting collect debug snapshot link instead of open debug snapshot link.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working by following these steps:

1. Install the SnapshotCollector nuget package in your website (Config can be found in the end of this post) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector
2. (IMP) - Publish in debug mode, make sure that the pdb files are deployed (You can check from the 'preview' option)

```html
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector">
      <!-- The default is true, but you can disable Snapshot Debugging by setting it to false -->
      <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
      <!-- Snapshot Debugging is usually disabled in developer mode, but you can enable it by setting this to true. -->
      <!-- DeveloperMode is a property on the active TelemetryChannel. -->
      <IsEnabledInDeveloperMode>true</IsEnabledInDeveloperMode>
      <!-- How many times we need to see an exception before we ask for snapshots. -->
      <ThresholdForSnapshotting>1</ThresholdForSnapshotting>
      <!-- The maximum number of snapshots we collect for a single problem. -->
      <MaximumSnapshotsRequired>3</MaximumSnapshotsRequired>
      <!-- The maximum number of problems that we can be tracking at any time. -->
      <MaximumCollectionPlanSize>50</MaximumCollectionPlanSize>
      <!-- How often to reset problem counters. -->
      <ProblemCounterResetInterval>24:00:00</ProblemCounterResetInterval>
      <!-- The maximum number of snapshots allowed per day. -->
      <SnapshotsPerDayLimit>30</SnapshotsPerDayLimit>
      <!--Whether or not to collect snapshot in low IO priority thread.-->
      <SnapshotInLowPriorityThread>true</SnapshotInLowPriorityThread>
  </Add>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issue. followed this link for installation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-snapshot-debugger. but in Azure portal, not showing "open Debug snapshot". only showing "collect snapshots" and on clicking this link redirecting to above mentioned url.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: can any one provide solution ?

Comment: have u checked whether u have permission as "Application Insights Snapshot Debugger" ?

Comment: I am also facing this problem. Were you able to find the resolution ? Please share